# How to pass image,title and description to Bootstrap Modal popup?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How i can pass image,title and description to bootstrap modal?
when one image link click the modal open with that image title and description.
my code is:

```
<?php                     
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project");

           $file_path = 'admin1\projectimages/';


while($post=mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
$id=$post['id'];
$ptitle=$post['Title'];
$image=$post['Image'];
$des=$post ['Description'];

$src = $file_path . $post['Image'];
echo'<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><a href="#modal" class="fa" data-toggle="modal"  data-placement="right"><h4 class="project_heading">'.$ptitle.'</h4></a>
                    <a href="#modal" class="fa ok " data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modal" data-placement="right"><img src='.$src.' style="width:250px; border:1px solid red;"></a></li>';}
?>
```

Modal Code:

```
<div class=" modal fade bs-example-modal-lg"  role="dialog"  id="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
    <a href="#modal" class="fa fa-times cls-pop" data-dismiss="modal" id="thanks" ></a>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg clearfix">
      <div class="modal-content pop-up">
<h3 >Title</h3>
               <div class="clearfix">
            <div>
              <img src="   "   style="width:99%; border:1px solid red;">
              <p></p><p ></p>
<p></p></div>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from PHP to HTML by using `echo`.

So here: `<h3 >Title</h3>`

you would put: `<h3><?PHP echo $ptitle; ?></h3>`

The shorter notation for this is `<?= $ptitle; ?>`

It will work just fine as long as 1) your HTML is working and 2) your variables are getting populated.

Comment: There are multiple images in database when we use your code it prints last image title ..

Answer (score 0):

Set image src in  tag

```
<li>
 <a href="#modal" class="fa open_model" data-toggle="modal"  data-placement="right"><h4 class="project_heading" data-imgsrc="'.$src.'" data-desc="'.$ptitle.'">'.$ptitle.'</h4>
</a>
<a href="#modal" class="fa ok open_model" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modal" data-placement="right" data-imgsrc="'.$src.'" data-desc="'.$ptitle.'">
```

In your model html

```
<div class="modal-content pop-up">
 <h3>Title</h3>
 <div class="clearfix">
 <div>
  <img id="model_img" src="" style="width:99%; border:1px solid red;">
  <p></p><p ></p><p></p>
 </div>
```

When you click on the link set the image src and description to model
set in your js file

```
$(document).on("click", ".open_model", function () {
     var imgSrc = $(this).data('imgsrc');
     var desc = $(this).data('desc');
     $(".modal-content #model_img").attr('src',imgSrc);
});
```

If you set it well than it will works

Comment: There is some problem that is disturbed other images which are displaying  .when i click on one image to open in modal it changes all image with that image which i have clicked.see: http://i.imgur.com/rLMHHHn.png

Comment: give one id to your  "<img src="   "  id="model_img">"

Comment: every time you click on image or description, it change your src

Comment: When i click on image it changes

Comment: you want to open model when ever you click on description or image, and in model you want to show particular image and description right ?